# How to destroy a canvas that is not in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, memory-management

I am making an HTML5 game that needs to be able to load an arbitrary number of different sprites, tilemaps, and layers.  (The graphics are uploaded by users, so storing them ahead of time is not an option.)  In order to do this, I create a separate "virtual" canvas for each object, using document.createElement("canvas").  These canvases are not added to the DOM; they are simply used to store frames for drawing onto the main screen.  However, this causes memory problems over time, as it seems that the virtual canvases are not automatically removed by the garbage collector when their relevant objects are destroyed.

Normally, one would remove a canvas by removing it from its parent element, but how does one destroy a canvas that is not part of the DOM in the first place?